# How I get the rating score from Facebook pages?

Tags: facebook

Like this

http://postimg.org/image/l6bq0bf5l/

It's show at popup.

I know that this feature has arrived for less than half yearand this feature don't have for every pages.

How I get that 4.2 score for using in my PHP?

Thanks.

PS. I try to use review table but I don't know how to use it. Place and page table, review and rating don't included.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the

```
/{page_id}/ratings
```

endpoint. See the docs here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/ratings/ Note that you need a Page Access Token for this.

Comment: Thanks, Tobi.

I use like this. [link](graph.facebook.com/my_interest_page_id/ratings) but I get this 

{
   "error": {
      "message": "(#210) Subject must be a page.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 210
   }
}

Did I do something wrong? From the last post, I don't know how to get access token yet.

Comment: Then "my_interest_page_id" is obviously not an object of type Page. To be honest, I'd recommend that you make yourself more comfortable with the basics of the FB Graph API first. You can receive a Page Access Token via https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me%2Faccounts but only if you already created a Page yourself.

Comment: OK, I'll be calm for Graph-API. Now I learn that /feed after page-id or page name, it shown the comment to limitation number. But I don't want this. I want rating score (0 to 5) for develop my app.

:)

Comment: I can use rating now, It show the review comment, rating point.

But It can use only my established pages.

If I use with any page, Do I violate them?

Because I want average ranking for developing my app only.

Comment: @tobi I am facing same problem as @ทักษกร-นิลดำ, I am calling `824413870916335/ratings` where `824413870916335` is my page ID and I am using page access token for it. I can get `824413870916335/feed` etc but not `ratings`. Any thought?

Comment: I the PageID `824413870916335` your own page?